# Глагол "жил" — переходный или непереходный?

Tags: морфология, глаголы

Глагол **жил** переходный или непереходный?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Глагол **ЖИТЬ** непереходный. Он относится к числу "самых непереходных", так называемых ЭКЗИСТЕНЦИАЛЬНЫХ глаголов. 
 Непереходные глаголы могут обозначать:
 1. физическое и психическое состояние: болеть, спать, грустить, радоваться 
 2. движение: ходить, бегать, лететь, плыть 
 3. существование: **жить**, быть, существовать... [здесь](http://www.goldrussian.ru/catalog/znachenie-perekhod-neperekhod-53.htm)

***Я живу в городе.*** Бесспорно непереходный.
***Живу здесь уже год***. Спорно. Формально глагол переходный. Фраза разговорного стиля, очень привычная. Но она построена не совсем точно. Ср.: Живу здесь в течение года.  Глагол непереходный.

То же самое можно сказать в связи с предложением "Он жил сто лет". (Ср.: Он жил в течение ста лет.) Жил СКОЛЬКО? КАК ДОЛГО? сто лет. "Сто лет" - цельное словосочетание, является в предложении обстоятельством. Вопрос ЧТО? здесь задать нельзя.
А вот глаголы ***ПРОЖИЛ, пережил*** действительно переходные, приставка сделала своё дело. Вопрос ЧТО? от них уже возможен. ***Он прожил сто лет.***  Хотя и от этого глагола вопрос КАК ДОЛГО? звучит более правильно. Ср.:*Он пережил сына на десять лет.*

О транзитивации глагола ЖИТЬ можно почитать [здесь](http://magazines.russ.ru/znamia/2007/3/ep18.html)

Comment: EkaterinaKas..., из текста получается что "прожил" переходный потому, что  "сто лет". Как-нибудь снимите недоразумение. 
Надо чтобы объект отвечал на вопрос "что?", а не "сколько?" или "как?". 
Прожить можно, например, жизнь. Хотя переходность и тут весьма слабая. А "сто лет" можно приклеить к любому глаголу, сто раз непереходному, даже возвратному. "Спал сто лет", "мечтал сто лет", "радовался сто лет".

Answer (score 0):

Вы серьезно? Жить - кого?

ЗЫ Давайте так, Вы объясняете, почему возникло затруднение - я отвечаю на вопрос в соответствии с рассказанным.

//-----------------
С учетом уже сказанного - очень кратко.

Для переходности надо чтобы объект был именно объектом, "принимающим" действие, т.е. отвечал на вопрос "что?" ("кого?"), а не "сколько?" или "как?".

Прожить можно, например, жизнь. Хотя переходность и тут весьма слабая. А "сто лет" можно приклеить к любому глаголу, сто раз непереходному, даже возвратному. "Спал сто лет", "мечтал сто лет", "радовался сто лет".

Comment: Спасибо, каким членом предложения является слово"сто"в предложении:"Он жил (прожил)сто лет?

Comment: Очень хороший вопрос.

Comment: Отлично сказано уважаемый Бehemothus,Значит слово "сто" будет обстоятельством?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, по современным представлениям количественное (хотя порядковое, вроде, тоже) числительное с последующим существительным всегда составляет единый член предложения. В данном случае обстоятельство - "сто лет".

Comment: behemothus! Совершенно верно!!! Сто лет - обстоятельство, выраженное сочетанием количественного числительного с существительным.

Comment: Да я не в верности сомневался, а в том, как это сейчас в школе подают...

Comment: И в школе так.

Answer (score 0):

Если от глагола можно  задать вопрос вин.пад. и получить ответ, имеющий право на жизнь, то глагол считается переходным.

Comment: Спасибо, это понятно. Каким членом предложения является слово"сто"в предложении:"Он жил (прожил)сто лет"?

Comment: Ну неверно же!!! Существительное должно быть в винительном падеже без предлога и со значением объекта. (Действие переходит на объект, потому и глагол называется переходным).

Comment: ну что делать... (((
Всеобщее образование.  
Про объектность вообще забывает девять из десяти... А ведь это "ключевое слово".

Comment: спасибо всем,а почему числительное с последующим существительным составляет единый член,а существительное с существительным вроде "стол ученика" не составляет единое целое,ведь это словосочетание тоже ближе к одному целому?

Comment: Вопрос "почему" - это уже ко Всевышнему.  
В земной жизни - поверьте на слово, что мир устроен именно так.

> а существительное с существительным вроде "стол ученика" не составляет единое целое  
  
Не составляет. А в чем сомнения? Фразу приведите, где это не так.  

ЗЫ Вы не станете уверять, фраза сохранит грамматику, убери Вы слово "сто"?

Comment: спасибо,все ясно,а я думал , оно составляет единое целое с последующим словом, потому что второе слово лишь определяет первое или выводит его из полной неопределенности,а само(второе) в предложении никакой роли не играет.

Comment: "Единое целое", как следует из названия, - неразложимое в рамках существующего синтаксиса сочетание.